# how can use $categoryId in function

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

here, I am generating **dynamic column** in **yii2 GridView**

```
$gridColumns = [];
$gridColumns[] = [
    'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
    'contentOptions' => ['width' => 10],
];

foreach ($CategoryList as $categoryId => $categoryName) {
    $gridColumns[] = [
        'label' => $categoryName,
        'value' => function($model) {
            return $categoryId;    <---- categoryId use in function
        }
    ];
}


GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
]);
```

how can i use categorId in gridView Closure function

every column has unique $categoryId like 1,2,3 accroding to loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($CategoryList as $categoryId => $categoryName) {

    $categoryIdVariable = "$categoryId"; <---- store value in a variable
    $$categoryIdVariable = $categoryIdVariable; <---- store variable in another variable


    $gridColumns[] = [
        'label' => $categoryName,
        'value' => function($model) use($categoryIdVariable) { <---- and use it like a string variable

            $categoryId = $categoryIdVariable;
            return $categoryId;    <---- dynamic categoryId use in function
        }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Anonymous function [use()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
$gridColumns[] = [
    'label' => $categoryName,
    'value' => function($model) use ($categoryId) {
        return $categoryId;
    }
];
```

Comment: this is not working, because of every column has unique $categoryId like 1,2,3

Comment: @ShringirajDewangan This answer's your question on how to use `$categoryId` in closure. Your comment is other question. Anyways, You will get `$categoryId` different everytime according to your loop. Clarify your question a bit.